# Is it possible (or sane) to check if an octal number is in range with regular expression?

Tags: regex, xsd

I have to check if the content of a given XML element representing an octal number is in the range 0-77776.

Is it possible to obtain this result only with regular expression? I have tried in many ways but somehow some case is not handled. I cannot find a single expression that matches 7 and 54327 and not 77777.

What other approach do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex works, but I can only get it working in perl so far. Hopefully whatever engine you're using will support it:

`^([0-7]{0,4}|[0-7]{4}(?(?<=^7777)[0-6]|[0-7]))$`

Example perl script:

```
sub verify {
    $num = shift;
    if ($num =~ m/^([0-7]{0,4}|[0-7]{4}(?(?<=^7777)[0-6]|[0-7]))$/) {
        print "$num: yes\n";
    }
    else { print "$num: no\n"; }
}

@nums = ("54327","7","77776","77777","77774");

foreach (@nums) {
    verify $_;
}
```

output:

```
54327: yes
7: yes
77776: yes
77777: no
77774: yes
```

Comment: Many thanks it worked. I needed just to escape the "<" char to make it work on my xsd